# Eclipse launch error shows org.osgi.framework.BundleException

Tags: eclipse-plugin, xtend

I have the following error during my generator development.

I tried several times to refresh my workspace but it'd not worked.

> org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module:
> org.artop.ecuc.gautosar.accessors.check [72]

> org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module:
> org.eclipse.emf.mwe2.language [123]

> org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module:
> org.eclipse.sphinx.emf.check [151]

> org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module:
> org.eclipse.sphinx.emf.mwe.dynamic [152]

> org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module:
> org.eclipse.xtend.core [168]

> org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.xtext.common.types [173]

> org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module:
> org.eclipse.xtext.xbase.testing

The messages were not meaningful enough for me to resolve the issue.

It looked like it was the version problem.
Anyone can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked throughout all plugins and I believed that they have been installed.
If your Eclipse environment doesn't have these kinds of plugins installed, you should check for installation.

[image]

In my case, the problem had come from my workspace.
I wiped out all data and make it again.

And after the new workspace finished to build, my application worked well. I think due to run-time exception of javaw (JRE), some plugins were broken, but just my guess.